Data type for 24-bit RGB image in C# when using the PCVips/OpenCV wrapper
I currently have code to support 16-bit grayscale image processing, and here currently the image is passed as a ushort parameter. So what datatype need to be used in case of 24-bit RGB, 32-bit RGBA type images?
Image processing is doing by a wrapper of the VIPS and OpenCV libraries, PCVips.

This question seems underspecified. What are the actual functions that are called? At least the answers ought to include them. Presumably the answerers know them. A lead: "C# software development: Processing 24-bit RGB images with PCVips/OpenCV wrappers"

For images, it is common to use a byte array to represent the pixel data, regardless of the pixel format. Most image processing libraries should have methods to accept a byte array, span, or pointer for the pixel data. A very simple image format might look something like:
public class MyImage{
    public byte[] Data {get; init;}
    public int Width {get; init;}
    public int Height {get; init;}
    public int Stride {get; init;}
    public MyPixelFormats Format {get; init;}
}

Indexing is done like Data[y * Stride + x * bytesPerPixel] to get the first byte of a pixel. I would recommend against using two-dimensional or three-dimensional arrays, since it tend to make interoperability more difficult.
Note that you can use spans to cast the array from one datatype to another without actually doing any copying. So you could make a common interface that exposes a Span<byte> Data, letting each implementation use whatever datatype they prefer.
Also note that 24-bit RGB do not have any equivalent 24-bit integer type, so you need to pay a little bit more attention to the stride and index operations. But when using a library most should accept some variant of the parameters above as the input/output.
